# Unity 3.8.12 Release Date

Tags: 11.04, unity, updates

I like to keep a tab on the development progress of Unity on Launchpad. Currently I am running Unity 3.8.10 on Natty. On launchpad it shows that Unity 3.8.12 "0day-SRU" was released like 3 days ago. However I have not got this update yet. I am eagerly waiting for it as it fixes many bugs that I face while using Unity.

**Why am I not getting the update? Also what does "oday-SRU" mean?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its a 0-day SRU (Stable Release Update). In simpler language:

1) An SRU is an updated version of a package which is uploaded for a release which has been released already. SRUs are more commonly known as 'software updates' and these are the things which come up in Update Manager.

2) 0-day SRU means that it is an update which will land **very soon** after the release of Ubuntu 11.04 (usually the same day as the release itself).

According to the SRU procedure, every SRU package should be first uploaded to the proposed repository. Then, the bugs fixed by it should be confirmed by a user as being fixed before the package could be moved to the main updates repository.

In this case, the Unity 3.8.12 package fixed 5 bugs, 3 of which have been verified (as of the time of posting this answer) and 2 are still in need of verification. The Unity 3.8.12 package is lying in the proposed repository, and will stay there until someone verifies the 2 remaining bugs. Once that is verified, then you'll get Unity 3.8.12 as an update from Update Manager. This should happen in a maximum of 4-5 days from now.

You can check the status of the Unity package in the proposed repository at [this](http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/pending-sru.html) link. Browse down until you reach `natty` and then look at the Unity package row. Under `changelog bugs`, a blue bug link is a bug which is awaiting verification, a green bug link is a bug which has been verified successfully by a user, and a red bug link is a bug which wasn't verified successfully (in other words, the bug fix didn't work).

If you are impatient and want the package right now, then you can enable the proposed repository in your system by following [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed) guide (WARNING: not recommended as the updates could be untested and might lead to regressions) and then you will get the Unity upgrade automatically. Once you've upgraded, then you can yourself verify a bugfix and go to the relevant bug page and comment that you've successfully verified the SRU. Also, tag the bug with `verification-done` and remove the `verification-needed` tag if you have verified the SRU successfully. If the bugfix doesn't work, then tag it with `verification-failed`.

Comment: `before the package could be moved the mainstream repository.` should be `before the package could be moved the updates repository.` The ubuntu archive is not touched after release. It gets freezed. All the new things have to come via update repo.

Comment: @Manish: I didn't mention that earlier as it may confuse him. Made the appropriate change now.

Comment: Thank you very much...nicely phrased answer! could not be anymore clearer.

Comment: I've seen that there are an SRU1 and SRU2 on the list for Unity: https://launchpad.net/unity/+milestones . Does this mean that we will see these SRUs for Natty?

Comment: @Andre: yes. The second SRU should have hit the repo by now.